# How can cluster redis over ip on networks

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I'm setting up redis cluster over local network, but I can't!

I've tried in my local *127.0.0.1) and work well! But over network forexample 192.168.30.* not work

redis.conf

port 7000
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
requirepass my_password

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have allowed traffic on port 7000, further....

**A node in the Redis cluster requires a defined port and a port higher than 10000. In your instance, TCP ports 7000 and 17000 are both required to be open. Ensure iptables or ufw is configured properly.**

If even after this you are unable to setup you redis-cluster, Please share your output logs.